# Merge the tags screen and display

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

While checking our tags for missing tag-wikis, I came over these two -- and from the questions tagged, I cannot see what makes them different.

**Currently:** 76 questions using [screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) and 25 questions using [display](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display).

I'd suggest to merge display into screen, and then make it a synonym to screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This synonym had actually already been suggested, so I went ahead and approved it (and merged the tags).