# Merging tags screen-timeout and screen-saver into screen

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

After [display has been merged into screen](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/merge-the-tags-screen-and-display/) already, I'd like to suggest several additional candidates I discovered while editing the tag-wiki for [screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen):

- [screen-timeout](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-timeout) (8 questions)
- [screen-brightness](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-brightness) (14 questions)
- [screensaver](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screensaver) (1 question)

Additionally, it *might* make sense for [orientation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orientation) (9 questions) as well -- as it also relates to "screen orientation" (and that's what the questions tagged thus refer to -- so there's no confusion it could have to do with GPS, compass, or the like).

Again, the former "tags" could be setup as synonyms for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, whereas [screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) and [display](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) were really just different ways of saying the same thing,and were proper synonyms. These all seem like specific cases where a specific aspect or behaviour is being asked about. I think people are likely to search for "screen timeout" or "screen brightness" so these are useful tags.

Though as the one question in Screensaver makes clear, that whole idea just doesn't make sense in Android at the moment, so it's debatable whether we need that tag at all. But if things like Android x86 take off and we start seeing Android in more devices like desktop-style machines, or when Android is running devices with expensive screens that are permanently connected to the mains power, like TVs, set top boxes and Ouyas then screensavers could become a real thing for Android in the future.

Comment: I'm with GAThrawn on this. screen-timeout and screen-brightness are in no wise the same thing. "screensaver" should just be removed from that question and allowed to die; it doesn't have any context on Android.